# string.decode() vs. unicode(string)

Tags: python, string, unicode, decode

```
myString = 'éíěřáé'
```

I need to decode this string to unicode.
Is there any difference between folowing usages and between these two methods in general?

```
myString.decode(encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')
```

and

```
unicode(myString, encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `unicode` constructor can take other types apart from strings:

```
>>> unicode(10)
u'10'
```

For the bytestring case, however, the two forms are mostly equivalent. Some encoding options are not valid for the `unicode` constructor as they do not result in unicode output, but are valid for the `.decode` method of bytestrings, such as `'hex'`:

```
>>> unicode('10', encoding='hex')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: decoder did not return an unicode object (type=str)
```

Answer (score 2):

They're essentially the same, but with some minor performance shortcuts in either case; `str.decode` knows that its argument is a string, so it can shortcut type checking of its argument, while `unicode.__new__` has shortcuts for some common encodings including UTF-8.

Both methods call into `PyCodec_Decode` in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x `str.decode()` may result in either a unicode object or another `str`. The `unicode()` function only works for the encodings that result in a unicode object.

For example:

```
>>> "x\x9cKLJ\x06\x00\x02M\x01'".decode('zip')
'abc'
>>> unicode("x\x9cKLJ\x06\x00\x02M\x01'", encoding='zip')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: decoder did not return an unicode object (type=str)
>>>
```

Note that internally they both work in much the same way as the call to `unicode()` is indicating that it did really decode the object and only then objected to the type of the result.